# create dynamic camera overlay that changes with scences

Tags: ios, objective-c, ticker, ios-camera, camera-overlay

Hi I am new to IOS developing. I've been searching for a while, just can not find a good example.

I like to create an app dynamically detect paper, 
The app should be able to generate dynamic camera overlay by analysing current camera scenes.

like Adobe Scan.
[image]

I can program the sampling and detection algorithm myself, 
but really not good on the IOS interface and technique.

I am using objective-C as programming language.

I like to know:

```
1, how to change the camera overlay in real time?

2, how should i put a ticker that repeatedly check camera scenes?

3, how can I access and modify a picture from iOS objective C?
```

Please give me some ideas or show me some examples.

Comment: I'm also interested in with this topic. Did you find a solution?